# Finding the basis of a line on a plane

Tags: geometry

Say if I have 2 points $P_1$, $P_2$ lying on a plane with known equation $ax+by+cz+d=0$,

How do I obtain the expression for the 2 basis (the equations of the 2 red lines; that lie on the same plane) of the line $L$ formed by $P_1$ and $P_2$?

[image]

Comment: So, you are asking how to find the basis of the vector space that is formed by the points of the line connected from the 2 points in the plane, right ?

Comment: Is the origin on the plane implied to be the point closest to the coordinate origin?

Comment: @CharalamposFilippatos I have edited the question for more clarity.

Comment: @ja72 Yes. You can assume that they belong to the same coordinate system

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The normal direction to the plane is $$\boldsymbol{n} = \pmatrix{ \frac{a}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \\ \frac{b}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} \\ \frac{c}{\sqrt{a^2+b^2+c^2}} } $$

One basis vector can be along the two points

$$ \boldsymbol{e}_1 = \pmatrix{ \frac{x_2-x_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}} \\ \frac{y_2-y_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}} \\ \frac{z_2-z_1}{\sqrt{(x_2-x_1)^2 + (y_2-y_1)^2 + (z_2-z_1)^2}} } $$

The second basis vector can be perpendicular to both

$$ \boldsymbol{e}_2 = \boldsymbol{n} \times \boldsymbol{e_1} $$

<sub>where $\times$ is the vector cross product</sub>

Answer (score 0):

Your question is not clear.  If you know the coordinates of the two points $P_1=(x_1,y_1,z_1)$ and $P_2=(x_2,y_2,z_2)$ then the line that contains  these points can be determined without knowing any plane and it's given by the equation:
$$
\vec x= t \vec u +  \vec{P_i}
$$
where $\vec u$ is the vector that orients the line and $\vec {P_i}$ is the vector pointing to one of the two given points. Explicitly it's:
$$
(x,y,z)^T=t(x_2-x_1,y_2-y_1,z_2-z_1)^T+(x_1,y_1,z_1)^T
$$

and, obviously we have infintely many planes from this line.

Comment: I have edited the question with a diagram for more clarity. I am looking for the equations of the 2 red lines that lie on the same plane as $P_1$ and $P_2$